How do I change the -with-rtsopts flags when I execute cardano-node?
I want to specify some extra flags like --nonmoving-gc and -N (with the right amount of CPU cores that I want my cardano-node to execute in - my server has 16 CPU cores) in my +RTS configuration.
What would be the correct way of adding these flags to my cardano-node run command?
This is my current setup (which should be default):
[("GHC RTS", "YES")
 ,("GHC version", "8.10.7")
 ,("RTS way", "rts_thr")
 ,("Build platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
 ,("Build architecture", "x86_64")
 ,("Build OS", "linux")
 ,("Build vendor", "unknown")
 ,("Host platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
 ,("Host architecture", "x86_64")
 ,("Host OS", "linux")
 ,("Host vendor", "unknown")
 ,("Target platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
 ,("Target architecture", "x86_64")
 ,("Target OS", "linux")
 ,("Target vendor", "unknown")
 ,("Word size", "64")
 ,("Compiler unregisterised", "NO")
 ,("Tables next to code", "YES")
 ,("Flag -with-rtsopts", "-T -I0 -A16m -N2 --disable-delayed-os-memory-return")
 ]

